# Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint ' ' in the referenced table ' '

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to upload this code below to MySQL server I get the error

> #1822 - Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'productselectronics_ibfk_1' in the referenced table
> 'products'

```
create table Shops(
    distance integer,
    num_workers integer,
    name varchar(20),
    id varchar(8) unique not null,
    store_type varchar(30),
    primary key(id)
);

create table Workers(
    id varchar(8) unique not null,
    name varchar(20),
    position varchar(20),
    primary key(id)
);
create table Products(
    id varchar(8) unique not null,
    name varchar(40),
    price double precision(7, 2),
    description varchar(255),
    availability boolean,
    num_in_stock integer,
    primary key(id)
);

create table ProductsElectronics(
    product_id varchar(8) unique not null,
    product_name varchar(40),
    foreign key(product_id, product_name) references Products(id, name),
    
    brand_name varchar(20)
);
```

I don't really ask questions here, I rather prefer to google it on my own, but I could not find the solution anywhere. Other solutions on SO did not work for me.

Comment: The FK must reference a key, but Products(id, name) is no key.

Comment: You can remove the product_name column from ProductsElectronics. You shouldn't store the name in two tables.

Comment: Also, declare product_name in Products as UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change Products table like:

```
create table Products(
    id varchar(8) unique not null,
    name varchar(40),
    price double precision(7, 2),
    description varchar(255),
    availability boolean,
    num_in_stock integer,
    primary key(id, name)
);
```

Look here working [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=82e16f56c47d11d1d9fc6656670845a5&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Also I mean you should not copy product name to ProductsElectronics table. I think is enough to add product_id as foreign key without name duplication:

```
create table Products(
    id varchar(8) unique not null,
    name varchar(40),
    price double precision(7, 2),
    description varchar(255),
    availability boolean,
    num_in_stock integer,
    primary key(id)
);

create table ProductsElectronics(
    product_id varchar(8) unique not null,
    foreign key(product_id) references Products(id),
    
    brand_name varchar(20)
);
```

Here another example [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=eda11d4ec25875e9d173c07bf2dd1d4c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)